# dynamically change name of <fa> element

Tags: angular, font-awesome

i'm actually trying to use angular-font-awesome (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome) to add icons in my project.
i installed the component like the guide said and the example in the page:

```
<fa name="cog" animation="spin"></fa>
```

works fine.
i now want to change the name dinamically. i try this

```
    <label *ngFor="let icon of config.icons; let i = index" >
      <fa name=[icon.name] animation="spin"></fa>
    </label>
```

but it does not work. Any clue how to achive that?

Comment: `[name]="icon.name"` when you want to bind a variable use the brackets on whatever you want to use a variable name to.

Comment: it said that name is not an attribute of fa

Comment: interesting... Never used `angular-font-awesome`, I guess I have to now try it myself, curious why it wouldn't work :)

Comment: It works perfectly fine when I now tried it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cr6wuh Don't know what's going on with your code and why it wouldn't work.

Comment: AJT_82 - It's inside an ngFor so need {{}} template syntax. I missed it too!

Comment: @RobinWebb, why do you think that would make any difference? ;) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iff37o?file=src/app/app.component.ts `name="{{item.name}}"` and `[name]="item.name"` are exactly the same, or does exactly the same thing.

Comment: AJT_82 You are absolutely correct. Wasn't totally concentrating when I wrote the answer. Both formats work to the same end.Updated below. Apologies.

Comment: Yeah that was my bad on code, both works fine. thansk for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either of the below.

```
<label *ngFor="let icon of config.icons">
    <fa [name]="icon.name" animation="spin"></fa>
</label>

<label *ngFor="let icon of config.icons; let i = index" >
  <fa name="{{icon.name}}" animation="spin"></fa>
</label>
```